# HTML 5 Boiler plate ant script with absolute paths

Tags: ant, html5boilerplate

I am using the html5boiler plate ant build scripts and i am trying to integrate this into my existing platform where i all my css and js files are included using absolute paths. For example:

```
             <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/common.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/overlay.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/base.js"></script>
        <!-- end scripts -->
```

However, when i run the build script it tells me the directory does not exist. That is because its not using a relative path to find the files. If i take off the leading / then i can get it to work becuase its relative to my project source folder. Any idea how i can get this working without taking that leading slash off? The idea is to be able to take an existing project and make it work without any changes besides adding the comments in.

**UPDATE**
 The following ANT code is from the html5boiler plate ant build.xml. Basically, my paths in the file.root.page are absolute like i static above. Therefore the scripts.ordered property is outputting file names with an absolute path. So when it gets to the  concat command it take an input of script.toconcat with are absolute paths starting with /static. I need to prepend a path to those absolute paths so i now have /content/test.war/static/js/common.js

So basically, im trying to prepend a path such as /content/test.war to the variable scripts.toconcat which under the covers is a list of absolute paths defined above.

```
<filelist id="file.root" dir="${dir.source}/../${dir.cssjsfileloc}" files="${file.root.page}"/>
    <echo message="Concatenating Main JS scripts based on ${file.root.page}..."/>
    <apply executable="java" parallel="false"
      outputproperty="scripts.ordered">
        <arg value="-cp"/>
        <arg value="${dir.build.tools}"/>
        <arg value="ScriptsToConcat"/>
        <first>
            <filelist refid="file.root"/>
        </first>
    </apply>
    <filelist id="scripts.toconcat" dir="./${dir.intermediateroot}/" files="${scripts.ordered}">
    </filelist> 
<!-- overwrite=no here means not to overwrite if the target is newer than the sources -->
    <concat destfile="./${dir.intermediate}/${dir.js}/scripts-concat.min.js" overwrite="no">
        <filelist refid="scripts.toconcat" />
    </concat>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is Ant.  Why not have an Ant task that runs after that one do the substitution?

You could call [replaceregexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) which is a directory paced task for file search and replace.

Comment: i dont want to edit the contents of a file. I would rather just edit the filelist directly. Check my ant task above